# How to copy directory permissions

Tags: python, permissions

I'm curious how to copy the permission from directory to another.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system? Which filesystem?

Comment: Linux and the normal linux filesystem permissions, no specific.

Comment: Please be more specific: Are you saying that directory "A", for example, with permissions of `drwxr-xr-x` for the current user, transfer those permissions to directory "B" or are you saying for each file in dir "A", transfer those same permissions to the equivalent file in dir "B"? Why did you tag this "Python"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`shutil.copymode`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copymode) should help you out. From the documentation:

> `shutil.copymode(src, dst)`
>
> Copy the permission bits from src to dst. The file contents, owner, and group are unaffected. src and dst are path names given as strings.

I tested this in Ubuntu Jaunty using Python 2.6.2 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentionned python, I assume you are looking for

```
shutil.copymode(src, dst)
```

See the documentation on [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try cp -a from_dir to_dir. It will maintain the permissions from the first directory.